# How do I add a task to Crontab

Tags: cron, script

I am making a program for the Raspberry Pi to use, as part of its installation, it need to add a task to crontab so that it will run on bootup.

I know if I type in crontab -e
then add the line "@reboot file/to/program" to the bottom it will do it.

But how do I do it with just a command in the terminal for my installation script to use?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't particularly specific to the Raspberry Pi, and a bit of googling reveals some very complete [cron overviews](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto). From your description, it sounds like you want to edit the system-wide crontab (e.g.`sudo nano /etc/crontab`) to add the @reboot clause.

Answer (score 1):

I have a number of crons that I add via my install script.  Works perfect.

```
sudo sh -c 'cat <<EOF > /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
00 * * * * curl http://example.org/ping/`hostname`
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/crontab.php
EOF'
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

If you want to do a manual check whether those crons have been added correctly:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

shows that everything is added as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option- you can place a file in `/etc/cron.d/`. The advantage of this is you own the whole file, so it's easier to install it and not worry about breaking other entries.

Example:

```
cat /etc/cron.d/hello
*/5 * * * * pi /home/pi/hello.sh
```

Note entries in system-level places like this also specify the username.